# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null"

Tags: android, openweathermap

I have a problem about showing weather app.
 My app using openweathermap API. 
When I run my app,Monitor showing

> error"ComponentInfo{com.....}java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   invalid provider: null" and tell me "No Location".

And this  is My JSON Data

```
public class Coord

    {
        public double lon { get; set; }
        public double lat { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string main { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }
        public double pressure { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public double temp_min { get; set; }
        public double temp_max { get; set; }
        public double sea_level { get; set; }
        public double grnd_level { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wind
    {
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public int deg { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clouds
    {
        public int all { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sys
    {
        public double message { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public int sunrise { get; set; }
        public int sunset { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Coord coord { get; set; }
        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        public string @base { get; set; }
        public Main main { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public int dt { get; set; }
        public Sys sys { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int cod { get; set; }
    }
```

I think that my code can't  get location,So I'm not sure what I do it.This is MainActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.thpa.a9019.weatherapplication.Common.Common;
import com.thpa.a9019.weatherapplication.Helper.Helper;
import com.thpa.a9019.weatherapplication.Model.OpenWeatherMap;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    TextView txtCity, txtLastUpdate, txtDescription, txtHumidity, txtTime, txtCelsius;
    ImageView imageView;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;
    private Location location;
    static double Iat, Ing;
    OpenWeatherMap openWeatherMap = new OpenWeatherMap();
    int MY_PERMISSION = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Control Button
        txtCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCity);
        txtLastUpdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLastUpdate);
        txtDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        txtHumidity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHumidity);
        txtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        txtCelsius = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCelsius);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //Get Coordinates
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{

                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,
                    Manifest.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS
            }, MY_PERMISSION);
        }
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location == null)
            Log.e("TAG", "No Location");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{

                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,
                    Manifest.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS
            }, MY_PERMISSION);
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{

                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,
                    Manifest.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS
            }, MY_PERMISSION);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Iat = location.getLatitude();
        Ing = location.getLongitude();

        new GetWeather().execute(Common.apiRequest(String.valueOf(Iat), String.valueOf(Ing)));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    private class GetWeather extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait....");
            progressDialog.show();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String stream = null;
            String urlString = params[0];
            Helper http = new Helper();
            stream = http.getHTTPData(urlString);
            return stream;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (s.contains("Error!! Not found city")) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                return;
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type mType = new TypeToken<OpenWeatherMap>() {
            }.getType();
            openWeatherMap = gson.fromJson(s, mType);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            txtCity.setText(String.format("%s,%s", openWeatherMap.getName(), openWeatherMap.getSys().getCountry()));
            txtLastUpdate.setText(String.format("Last Update: %s", Common.getDateNow()));
            txtDescription.setText(String.format("%s", openWeatherMap.getWeather().get(0).getDescription()));
            txtHumidity.setText(String.format("%d%%", openWeatherMap.getMain().getHumidity()));
            txtTime.setText(String.format("%s/%s", Common.unixTimeStampToDateTime(openWeatherMap.getSys().getSunrise()), Common.unixTimeStampToDateTime(openWeatherMap.getSys().getSunset())));
            txtCelsius.setText(String.format("%.2f °C", openWeatherMap.getMain().getTemp()));
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(Common.getImage(openWeatherMap.getWeather().get(0).getIcon()))
                    .into(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```